# Having trouble with XML namespaces in T-SQL

Tags: xml, t-sql, xml-namespaces

I had success in parsing some XML files, and handling the namespace involved.
However I've now come to some XMLs from a different source, and things are not working the same !

Here is my XML (simplified)

```
<ConnectionExport xmlns="http://www.sap.com/IS/Connection" version="14.2.4.732">
    <Connection>
        <technical_name>mytechname</technical_name>
    </Connection>
    <Connection>
        <technical_name>mytechname</technical_name>
    </Connection>
</ConnectionExport>
```

and my code to parse

```
        SELECT 
            T.c.query('.')
            ,T.c.value('(@version)','nvarchar(250)')as [version]
            ,CN.c.query('.') as [connection]
        FROM   
        @xml.nodes('
            declare namespace cnn="http://www.sap.com/IS/Connection";
            (cnn:ConnectionExport)
            ') T(c)
            outer apply
            T.c.nodes('
                Connection
            ') as CN(c)
```

The first 2 columns return all as expected, the full XML text, and the [version] value.
However, CN.c.query('.') is simply NULL.

I know it's something to do with the namespace because it works just fine is I strip all namespace concerns from the XML file and SQL.

Googled a lot ... but still struggling to grasp the concept of what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Found it !!

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://www.sap.com/IS/Connection' AS ns)
    SELECT 
        T.c.query('.')
        ,T.c.value('(@version)','nvarchar(250)')as [version]
        ,CN.c.query('.') as [connection]
        FROM   
            @xml.nodes('ns:ConnectionExport') T(c)
            outer apply
            T.c.nodes('ns:Connection') as CN(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the namespace is *default namespace*, you can simplify the query by registering the namespace as *default* using `;WITH XMLNAMESPACES` :

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (default 'http://www.sap.com/IS/Connection')
SELECT 
    T.c.query('.')
    ,T.c.value('(@version)','nvarchar(250)')as [version]
    ,CN.c.query('.') as [connection]
    FROM   
        @xml.nodes('ConnectionExport') T(c)
        outer apply
        T.c.nodes('Connection') as CN(c)
```

This way, all elements in xquery implicitly considered in default namespace, unless otherwise specified. No need of adding the same prefix everytime we want to refer to an element in the xquery.